# Undefined variable in isset()

Tags: php, undefined

Can be closed, lost the overview in my project and worked in a file, that has the same name and method. So no changes were made. It works now. Sorry for wasting your time. My mistake.

I have a static factory method in which I'm trying to get the classname of the parameter.

```
static function factory($row)
{
  if (is_null($classname)) {
    $classname=get_called_class();
  }
```

Error Output:

> [Tue Sep 23 18:35:24.078345 2014] [:error] [pid 9971] [client
>   127.0.0.1:45702] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: classname in /var/www/dev/lib/class.base.php on line 9, referer:

```
> http://localhost/dev/app.php?action=do
```

When I try to set the $classname = null; before check it, there is also a undefined variable error. Same thing with isset($classname). What have i done wrong?

Here is another example, thhat doesn't work for me:

```
 class definetest{
 static function factory()
    {
      if (is_null($classname)) {
        $classname=get_called_class();
      }
      return $classname;
    }

}

$x = new definetest();

echo $x::factory();
```

It returns the classname, but I have an error in my apache log

Comment: [unable to reproduce this](https://eval.in/197586)

Comment: Maybe this is too simple, but are you actually creating the variable anywhere on your script?

Comment: $classname = null;  where did you put that?

Comment: can be closed, lost the overview in my project and worked in a file, that has the same name and method. So no changes were made. It works now. Sorry for wasting your time. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static function factory($row)
{
  if (isset($classname)) {
    $classname = get_called_class();
  }
}
```

If you use isset() before call to variable. It is not possible to show notice undefined variable.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php isset — Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL